# What is the use of feholdexcept etc.?

Tags: c, exception, floating-point, signals, fenv

The documentation (in the standards) for all of `fenv.h` is rather confusing, but I'm especially confused about `feholdexcept` and the concept of "non-stop mode" for a floating point exception. As far as I can tell, on any IEEE floating point implementation, exceptions are non-signaling/"non-stop" by default, and the `fenv.h` interfaces seem to provide no way to enable a signaling mode unless it was the default. Is the whole concept of `feholdexcept` useless except on non-IEEE systems or systems with nonstandard extensions for setting the signaling exception mask?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose that you're implementing a library, and you don't know anything about what your callers might do the the floating-point environment before calling your code.  They might unmask an exception, and install a custom trap handler that causes division-by-zero to produce the value 42.  Suppose that your library depends on having default IEEE-754 behavior for division-by-zero.  The `feholdexcept` function gives you a means to enforce this behavior.  The caller's environment, complete with their unmasked exception, can then be restored using the `fesetenv` function.

This is admittedly a fairly obscure corner case of usage, but frankly *everything* in `fenv.h` is fairly obscure to most programmers.

Comment: Considering that for the standard library, unless otherwise documented all functions need to be called in the default floating point environment to behave according to the specification, I think it would be pretty reasonable for third-party library authors to also put the burden on the calling application. Especially since any use of `fe*` functions might trigger the compiler (albeit not GCC...) to omit floating point optimizations that could cause exceptions to be lost...

Comment: @R..: The `<fenv.h>` functions are generally somewhat lacking in both design and in documentation.  I would go so far as to say that they might be the weakest feature of the C library.  If you have any suggestions for improvements, I would be happy to pass them on to the C floating-point working group.